# How to deseralize an int array into a custom class with Moshi?

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization, moshi

I use [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) to deserialize the following JSON file:

```
{
    "display": "Video 1",
    "isTranslated": false,
    "videoSize": [
        1920,
        1080
    ]
}
```

... using the following model class:

```
public class Stream {

    public final String display;
    public final boolean isTranslated;
    public final int[] videoSize;

    public Stream(String display,
                  boolean isTranslated,
                  int[] videoSize) {
        this.display = display;
        this.isTranslated = isTranslated;
        this.videoSize = videoSize;
    }

}
```

This works as expected.

---

Now, I would like to **replace** the `int[]` with a dedicated `VideoSize` class which maps the two integer values into named fields such as:

```
public class VideoSize {

    public final int height;
    public final int width;

    public VideoSize(int width, int height) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

}
```

Is this possible with a [custom type adapter](https://github.com/square/moshi#custom-type-adapters) or somehow else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this adapter:

```
public class VideoSizeAdapter {

    @ToJson
    int[] toJson(VideoSize videoSize) {
        return new int[]{videoSize.width, videoSize.height};
    }

    @FromJson
    VideoSize fromJson(int[] dimensions) throws Exception {
        if (dimensions.length != 2) {
            throw new Exception("Expected 2 elements but was " + 
                Arrays.toString(dimensions));
        }
        int width = dimensions[0];
        int height = dimensions[1];
        return new VideoSize(width, height);
    }

}
```