# Using Moshi with multiple input fields

Tags: kotlin, moshi

I have some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "name" : "Credit Card",
    "code" : "AUD",
    "value" : 1000
}
```

and am using Moshi to unmarshall this into a data structure like:

```
data class Account(
    @Json(name = "name")
    val name: String,

    @Json(name = "currency")
    val currency: String,

    @Json(name = "value")
    val value: Int
)
```

Everything works well.  However, I really would like to extract the `currency` and `value` parameters into a separate `Money` object. So my model looks more like:

```
data class Money(
    @Json(name = "currency")
    val currency: String,

    @Json(name = "value")
    val value: Int
)

data class Account(
    @Json(name = "name")
    val name: String,

    @Json(name = "???")
    val money: Money
)
```

The challenge I'm struggling with is how to annotate things so that the `Money` object can be given two different fields (`currency` and `value`) that come from the same level as the parent account.

Do I need to create an intermediate "unmarshalling" object called, say, `MoshiAccount` and then use a custom adapter to convert that to my real `Account` object?

I saw [How to deseralize an int array into a custom class with Moshi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920735/how-to-deseralize-an-int-array-into-a-custom-class-with-moshi) which looks close (except that in that case, the adapted object (VideoSize) only needs a single field as input... in my case, I need both `currency` and `value`)

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moshi's adapters can morph your JSON structure for you.

```
object ADAPTER {
  private class FlatAccount(
      val name: String,
      val currency: String,
      val value: Int
  )

  @FromJson private fun fromJson(json: FlatAccount): Account {
    return Account(json.name, Money(json.currency, json.value))
  }

  @ToJson private fun toJson(account: Account): FlatAccount {
    return FlatAccount(account.name, account.money.currency, account.money.value)
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add the adapter to your Moshi instance.

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(Account.ADAPTER).add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
val adapter = moshi.adapter(Account::class.java)
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.Essentially, I need to create an intermediate unmarshalling object and then transform that into my real object.

While this would work perfectly for a single instance (eg. Account), however, it also implies I need to create an unmarshalling clone for *every* type that contains a Money object. So much boilerplate :-(

Appreciate the answer though...

Comment: @CraigEdwards JsonAdapter.Factory is where the real power is. You may be able to make a more generalalized solution with it.